# How to set standard cityOutlet in geocoding?

Tags: ios, geocoding

I'm making a application where the user sets the adres in an `UITextField` and gets a location on the map.
I want the cityOutlet to be invisible but be fixed at the city 'Amsterdam'.

Is there an way to do this? I couldn't find a way to fix this, or am I stupid..

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *addressOutlet;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *cityOutlet;

@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocation *selectedLocation;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary *placeDictionary;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

  self.addressOutlet.delegate = self;
  self.cityOutlet.delegate = self;
  self.mapView.delegate = self;

  self.placeDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
  CLLocationCoordinate2D zoomLocation;
  zoomLocation.latitude = 40.740848;
  zoomLocation.longitude= -73.991134;
  MKCoordinateRegion viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(zoomLocation, 1609.344,1609.344);
  [self.mapView setRegion:viewRegion animated:YES];

}

- (void)updatePlaceDictionary {

  [self.placeDictionary setValue:self.addressOutlet.text forKey:@"Street"];
  [self.placeDictionary setValue:self.cityOutlet.text forKey:@"City"];
}

- (void)updateMaps {

    CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    [geocoder geocodeAddressDictionary:self.placeDictionary completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
      if([placemarks count]) {
        CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
        CLLocation *location = placemark.location;
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = location.coordinate;
        [self.mapView setCenterCoordinate:coordinate animated:YES];
      } else {
        NSLog(@"error, geen adres gevonden");
      }
    }];

}

- (void)delayedReverseGeocodeLocation {

  [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];

  [self reverseGeocodeLocation];
}

- (void)reverseGeocodeLocation {

  CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
  [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:self.selectedLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {

    if(placemarks.count){
      NSDictionary *dictionary = [[placemarks objectAtIndex:0] addressDictionary];
      [self.addressOutlet setText:[dictionary valueForKey:@"Street"]];
      [self.cityOutlet setText:[dictionary valueForKey:@"City"]];
    }
  }];
}

- (IBAction)submitTapped:(id)sender {
  [self updatePlaceDictionary];
  [self updateMaps];
}
```

Comment: Why do you want the outlet to be hidden and have a fixed value? If you don't use it you should just use an `NSString` property/ivar.

Comment: Very true Aaron. Sorry for the mistyping. I want the UITextField to be hidden, but not the Outlet.

Comment: But your `UITextField` *is* a `IBOutlet`. You probably just want a string property, not a label or an outlet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `-viewDidLoad` to hide the `UILabel` outlet and set its text try this:

```
self.cityOutlet.text = @"Amsterdam";
self.cityOutlet.hidden = YES;
```

Then comment out/remove this line in your reverse geocode location method:

```
//[self.cityOutlet setText:[dictionary valueForKey:@"City"]];
```

Alternatively, if you're not using the `cityOutlet` label for anything but holding a string, try just using an `NSString` property in your implementation file instead of the outlet.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* cityName;
```